# Is it possible to migrate a postgresql database without downtime?

Tags: postgresql, migration, barman

I have a Postgresql Database on my Centos, I use barman to backup my database, my question is that is it possible to migrate my database to another server without downtime?
I know some solutions with small downtime with pg_start_backup(), barman also can handle it, but is there anyway to do it without down time? 
And one more question is, what is the best way to migrate it?

Comment: Version of Postgres?

Comment: The Postgresql version is 9.4

Answer (score 7):

If you need to migrate to the same version of postgres, then you can setup slave of your db on new server with [streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hot-standby.html) and then just promote it to master. There will be no downtime while doing `pg_basebackup`, maybe just some load on disks and network caused by your whole cluster moving to new server.